# Why two get requests are not updating fields in thingspeak?

Tags: python, iot, get-request

A single run cannot update two or more get request to my thingspeak fields.
My code has a part which requires two fields to get updated in one python program.
Like..,

```
urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=D------MQV&field1=5")
urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=D------MQV&field2=10")
```

Only field1 gets updated with the above example.
Thanks!

Comment: The sample mentioned was an alternative. Also tried the following.. requests.get("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=D-------MQV&field2=0". Same problem persists

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update up to 8 fields at once in one request.

urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=D------MQV&field1=5&field2=10")

The reason why two back-to-back requests do not work is that ThingSpeak has a [15-second rate limit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/channel-settings.html#rates) on free accounts.